# Replace all variable links with common domain

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Sorry if the title isn't clear enough however I'll explain exactly what I want here.

I'm using notepadd ++ to edit lines and data. My data is a list of thousands of links and I found some unwanted links that I wanna bulk remove them.

```
http://url.domain.com/1****
http://url.domain.com/2****
http://url.domain.com/3****
http://url.domain.com/4****
http://url.domain.com/5****
```

You can see the common is "url.domain.com" however the link is different is there a way to remove them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and replace:

- find what: `^http://url\.domain\.com.*$`
- replace with: (empty string)
- select **regular expression option**

where:

- `^` and `$` are beginning and end of line respectively
- `http://url\.domain\.com` is the domain you want to remove (`.` needs to be escaped by `\`)
- `.*` is anything following your domain in the same line

### Update

`^http://url\.domain\.com.*\r\n` removes line break too.

Comment: Thank you guys you saved my day it worked but i have to retry multiple times. Anyway one last thing after replacing with empty string it leaves empty lines can I remove them?

Comment: @Zaher: I've updated my answer, it should work now.

Comment: thanks for the update should I add $ to the end or no need? ^http://url\.domain\.com.*\r\n$?

Comment: it's working for me also without $, I've excluded it as I'm not confident how to use \r\n and $ together as both have similar meaning